# How are nested structures with different alignments laid out in memory?

Tags: c++, structure, memory-alignment

I'm a C# developer, writing a client for a server written in C++.  The server streams some arbitrary data over TCP/IP to the client, and we have to reassemble it on the other end.  The server sends us first a description of the data, then the data itself.

Problematic Structure:

```
struct Inner_S
{
  double a;
  double b[4][4];
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct Packed_S
{
  uint8_t c;
  Inner_S d;
};
```

The server is telling the client that the outer structure has an alignment of 1, and the inner structure has an alignment of 8.  The protocol spec says:

> Alignment of fields within a streamed structure is done according to the Itanium 64-bit C++ Application Binary Interface specification (i.e. the same as a typical GNU compiler on a typical 64-bit platform).

I found the [Itanium 64-bit C++ Application Binary Interface specification](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html).  I think the part I am looking for is in "Allocation of Members Other Than Virtual Bases" but I get lost in there.

On the C# side I'm reading the data stream and packing my own class with the values extracted from the structure.  I need to know where exactly in the stream to look for each element of the structure.

I'm currently handling the structure this way which is wrong according to my users:

(begin structure with alignment 1)(no padding needed)(read simple value)c(begin inner structure with alignment 8)(add padding to alignment 8)0000000(read field)aaaaaaaa(begin array)(read simple value)bbbbbbbb.....

That method is supported by [at least one site.](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tpf.toolkit.compilers.doc%2Fref%2Flangref_zos%2Fclrc03zos_nstructal.htm)

So, when I'm parsing this data, how do I handle alignment in `Inner_S`?

caaaaaaaabbbbbbbb.... (I think?)
caaaaaaaa0000000bbbbbbbb.... (looks wrong)

Comment: You know, a simple C++ program that prints out the `sizeof` your types and `offsetof` each of your fields would help you debug this sort of thing a lot quicker! :-)

Comment: That is an excellent idea.

Comment: One problem with determining this by experimentation is that the way it is done is compiler specific, it is not a language feature.  I think if I use GCC on different platforms it will work the same way but I'm not sure?

Comment: The particular problem the client was complaining about was fixed by doing alignment from the start of a structure rather than from any sort of global reference, and adding padding at the end of the structure instead of letting it's container resume control of alignment right away.  This is still hardly a concise and complete description of what is supposed to happen, and results a memory layout that negates the point of the inner structure having a pack of 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @Cameron I tried this with `offsetof` since this involves POD types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

struct Inner_S
{
  double a;
  double b[4][4];
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct Packed_S
{
  uint8_t c;
  Inner_S d;
};

int main() {
    cout << "Size: " << sizeof(Packed_S) << endl;
    cout << "c offset: " << offsetof(Packed_S, c) << endl;
    cout << "d offset: " << offsetof(Packed_S, d) << endl;
    cout << "a offset: " << offsetof(Packed_S, d.a) << endl;
    cout << "b offset: " << offsetof(Packed_S, d.b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Size: 137
c offset: 0
d offset: 1
a offset: 1
b offset: 9
```

So using your notation the structure is packed as `caaaaaaaabbbbbbbb....`. Note that if you take out the `#pragma pack(1)` directive the compiler adds 3 bytes of padding after `c`.

[See here](http://ideone.com/NFhtmD)

Comment: You compiling 32 bit?  I'd expect 7 bytes of padding without #pragma  pack(1) on a 64 bit compile.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore This gives me exactly the same result with a 64 bit compiler.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a compiler setting for default packing that's different between our environments?

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: I doubt it, `pack(1)` tells the compiler not to add any padding

Comment: But Inner_S is not under the pack(1) directive.  Otherwise there would be no padding at all, not 3 vs 7.

Comment: I get 7 bytes of padding using 64-bit g++ compiling for `-m64`. I think @sjdowling is using a 64-bit compiler executable, but compiling for 32 bits (the equivalent of `-m32` for g++).

Comment: @MarkLakata I was definitely producing 64 bit executables. My target was x86_64-w64-mingw32 and the compiler was gcc version 4.7.3.

Comment: `g++ junk.cpp -o junk -std=c++11 -x86_64-w64-mingw32` gives me an executable with 8 byte alignment. Can you run `file junk`? Mine says: `junk: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64,...`

Comment: This is exactly why I squealed when the first version of the spec said that the packing would be done like any standard C++ compiler would do it.  As far as I can see it's not standardized.  I made the spec writer put something more specific, that's when I got that other specification I have not spent enough time picking apart to understand.